# Codeigniter - Fazer Busca MySql e mostrar a quantidade de registro

Tags: php

Caros amigos.

Estou montando uma rotina em Codeigniter e gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa no Mysql e mostrar na tela para o usuário, quantas imagens já foi anexada para o imóvel.

Por exemplo: 
(Total: 5 de 20) ===> em um total de 20 imagens já foi anexada 05 e falta 15 para ser anexar.

Como faço essa pesquisa usando Codeigniter ?

Observação: usando apenas o PHP (normal) consigo, mas com o Codeigniter, estou enfrentando esse problema.

Alguém teria algum exemplo dessa parte.

Grato,

Cesar

Comment: Como você faria utilizando o "PHP normal"?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o

```
$this->db->count_all('nome_tabela');
```

ou voce pode fazer um count no seu result

```
count($query->result());
```

Answer (score 0):

Caro amigo saudações...

fiz da seguinte forma na pasta modell:

```
    //Soma a quantidade de imagens por imóvel
    public function count_anexos($id){
        $sql = "SELECT an.idAnexos, an.imoveis_idImoveis, im.idImoveis, COUNT(an.imoveis_idImoveis) AS total
                  FROM imoveis im
            INNER JOIN anexos an ON an.imoveis_idImoveis = im.idImoveis
                 WHERE an.imoveis_idImoveis = '$id' ";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result->row()->total;
    }
```

o problema é que quando incluo ou excluo alguma imagem, o total não atualiza, se não pressionar F5.

gostaria que pudesse atualizar automaticamente.

Grato,

Cesar

Comment: A então nesse caso você precisa usar requisições por ajax com o java script, da uma pesquisada sobre.